# iPhone css issue

Tags: iphone, css, conditional-statements

On [this site](http://svadsi.info), there are issues with the right column overlapping the left column.  This is the target CSS:

```
#content {
    margin: 0 34% 0 7.6%;
    width: 59.4%;
}

.left-sidebar #content {
    margin: 0 7.6% 0 35%;
    width: 65.4%;
}
```

Is there an issue with percentages margins in the iphone that is not being targeted correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that your container sizes are over 100% -

content - 34+7.6+59.4 = 101

left-sidebar - 7.6+35+65.4 = 108

Try adjusting your percentages first.

-- Edit --

Ok, first of all, the CSS you posted is for the same container on the page you linked. the left-sidebar class is only used in the body tag and it is the more specific selector so the first bit of CSS is being ignored. Also, those percentages are being calculated from the size of the parent container which is #primary. Your problem is between #primary and #secondary it would seem. #secondary is being specified as 27.2%, but that is irrelevant because it is being forced to 332px by it's child #bluebox - it is set to 330px wide and a 1px border. You will need to take that in to account because #secondary will always be a minimum of 332px wide due to #bluebox.

Comment: No, this doesn't work either.  I changed them to #content {
    margin: 0 34% 0 7.6%;
    width: 58.4%;
}

.left-sidebar #content {
    margin: 0 7.6% 0 34%;
    width: 56.4%;
}

Comment: Hi Brent, thank you for your feedback.  I can't seem to target the trouble area though.  I've tried adjusting the sidebars, and resetting the margins in the media specific areas.  Still can't get it to be set straight.

Comment: You are not changing the size of #bluebox. You have set that size as an absolute px and everything else is a percentage. You have the same problem on Android as well, not just iOS. Look at line 118 in style.css. Until you change the size of that box you will continue to have issues.

Comment: Well, the div #bluebox has elements inside of it that are relatively positioned.  Regardless, I made the width to be 100%, which on a computer takes the #bluebox div to be 100% of the parent element, .left-sidebar #secondary, but on the mobile device it will take up 100% of the screen width, and not the parent element.  This is with removing the absolute positioning as well.  Thank you again Brent.

Comment: You'll have to re-engineer the page. You can't really mix pixel widths and percentages and have everything work because sooner or later the pixel width will exceed the calculated percentage width. It would be a lot easier to simply use a standard 960 grid. iOS and Android are very good at resizing websites when you stick to static width.

Comment: Thanks Brent.  I'm still stuck because I'm redoing all of the mobile styles in percentages, but still having the same issues with the overlapping.